# Avoid polluting JavaScript global scope / top-level file scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to avoid polluting the top-level scope of my file - I am trying to encapsulate the variables into a closure.

**Current code:**

```js
// global scope - I want to keep track fo these variables between function calls
const timeInMsToReleaseNotification = 1000 * 15; // 15 seconds
let queuedNotifications: Notification[] = [];
let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

const trackNotifications = (data: Notification) => {
  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }

  queuedNotifications.push(data);

  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    const foundData = queuedNotifications[0];

    if (foundData) {
      displayNotification(
        foundData,
        queuedNotifications.length > 1
          ? 'nearbyBatch'
          : 'nearbySingle',
      );
      queuedNotifications = [];
      timeoutId = null;
    }
  }, timeInMsToReleaseNotification);
};
```

**How I would like it to work:**

```js
const trackNotifications = (data: Notification) => {
  const timeInMsToReleaseNotification = 1000 * 15; // 15 seconds
  let queuedNotifications: Notification[] = [];
  let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
  
  return () => {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    queuedNotifications.push(data);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      const foundData = queuedNotifications[0];

      if (foundData) {
        displayNotification(
          foundData,
          queuedNotifications.length > 1
            ? 'nearbyBatch'
            : 'nearbySingle',
        );
        queuedNotifications = [];
        timeoutId = null;
      }
    }, timeInMsToReleaseNotification);
  }
};

// calling fn like this
trackNotifications(data)()
```

This is not working atm.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you define not working,  are you calling `trackNotifications` more than once?, as this will create multiple instances..

Comment: @Keith Yes I am calling trackNotifications many times.

Comment: Just a heads up -> `NodeJS.Timeout`, if your using Node, you won't be polluting the global anyway.   One reason to use modules in both Node & now the browser, they don't by definition pollute the global..  eg.  Doing `const xyz = '123'` inside a module called `bob` will have `xyz` scoped to the module `bob`, not to the global.

Comment: @Keith Ah nice - I didn't know that. I would like to however avoid declaring vars at the top-level scope of my file. It feels a bit dirty to me. This is the reason why I am trying to find a way to encapsulate everything into one function. I could use a class (singleton) but it seems overkill for what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: I can assure you it's not dirty, and is a very common pattern.  All you would need to do is export your `trackNotifications` and it's a nice clean solution.  What's even nicer is if you keep your modules nice and small, in a way you have a kind of class encapsulation anyway, without using a class.  A module like this is how you would implement a singleton too.

Comment: Yeah agreed - I guess the file itself is the class. Thank you for the explanation @Keith!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is wrap the whole thing within an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). This limits the scope of the variables so only `trackNotifications` can access them.

```
const trackNotifications = (function () {
  const timeInMsToReleaseNotification = 1000 * 15; // 15 seconds
  let queuedNotifications: Notification[] = [];
  let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

  // executed when you call `trackNotifications(data)`
  return (data: Notification) => {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    queuedNotifications.push(data);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      const foundData = queuedNotifications[0];

      if (foundData) {
        displayNotification(
          foundData,
          queuedNotifications.length > 1
            ? 'nearbyBatch'
            : 'nearbySingle',
        );
        queuedNotifications = [];
        timeoutId = null;
      }
    }, timeInMsToReleaseNotification);
  };
})();

// call the function like this
trackNotifications(data);
```

Comment: Wouldnt the var `queuedNotifications` be recreated on every call here?

Comment: @WalterMonecke No. Only the contents of the returned function is executed when you call `trackNotifications(data)` multiple times. Initializing `queuedNotifications` is not part of that function. The only time that `queuedNotifications` is reset, is when you re-create the `trackNotifications` function. See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/3limin4t0r/pen/oNavgYx) example, and spam press "queue". You'll see that the queue does not reset.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `trackNotifications()` you create a new, empty `queuedNotifications` array. You need to wrap all the code in an IIFE to create a closure, so the declaration of `queuedNotifications` is outside the `trackNotifications()` function.

```js
((data) => {
  const timeInMsToReleaseNotification = 1000 * 15; // 15 seconds
  let queuedNotifications: Notification[] = [];
  let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

  const trackNotifications = (data: Notification) => {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    queuedNotifications.push(data);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      const foundData = queuedNotifications[0];

      if (foundData) {
        displayNotification(
          foundData,
          queuedNotifications.length > 1 ?
          'nearbyBatch' :
          'nearbySingle',
        );
        queuedNotifications = [];
        timeoutId = null;
      }
    }, timeInMsToReleaseNotification);
  };

  trackNotifications(data);
})(data);
```

However, in ES6 you don't need a closure for this. Variables declared with `let` and `const` are block-scoped, so you can simply put all the code inside a block.

```js
{
  const timeInMsToReleaseNotification = 1000 * 15; // 15 seconds
  let queuedNotifications: Notification[] = [];
  let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

  const trackNotifications = (data: Notification) => {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    queuedNotifications.push(data);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      const foundData = queuedNotifications[0];

      if (foundData) {
        displayNotification(
          foundData,
          queuedNotifications.length > 1 ?
          'nearbyBatch' :
          'nearbySingle',
        );
        queuedNotifications = [];
        timeoutId = null;
      }
    }, timeInMsToReleaseNotification);
  };

  trackNotifications(data);
}
```

Comment: Yep, I get your explanations - thank you! However, it doesn't really look clean to me somehow.

Comment: What's unclean about it? All the variables are local to the IIFE or block, nothing is in the global scope except for the `data` variable that it passes to the function.

Comment: It **IS** clean from a working standpoint: it works and everything is scoped to the {}. However, for my code taste, it just doesn't look clean. Idk how to explain it. I think I am looking for something where I just call a plain function without an IIFE or wrapping curly braces that is capable of keeping track of the internal state. Maybe that is just not possible with JS fns.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like C's static local variables. JS doesn't have anything like that.